# How can use Angular to bind to the page size in a print style sheet

Tags: angular, printing, styles, size

I want to bind to a print style sheet and set the page size programmatically.  Something like this:

```
@page {
    size: {{ width +'mm' }}  {{ height + 'mm' }}
}
```

How can this be done in Angular?

Comment: Did you consider this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet#obtaining_a_stylesheet ?

Comment: That is quite hacky but it works.  I am now able to iterate over the cssRules, find the one that contains the @page directive, delete it and insert an alternative rule with the relevant page dimensions in its place.
Thank you Aviad.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Aviad P.

In order to change the @page css directive under software control, I iterate over the CSSRules in document.styleSheets, find the one that contains a @page directive, delete it and insert a new rule in its place.

I would have expected Angular to enable binding to this as it does for so many other elements but at least this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done either through the component or on the html template:

```
printComponent(cmpName) {
     let printContents = document.getElementById(cmpName).innerHTML;
     let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

you can set your sizes and template as you desire
or you can accomplish this via css

```
@media print {
  app-root > * { display: none; }
  app-root app-print-layout { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: That does not look like Angular.  I don't understand your suggestion regarding CSS.  Where is the page size and how can I bind Angular expressions to it?